# Создать массив из двух списков и заменить повторяющие в первом

Tags: python

Есть два массива

```py
a = [123, 231, 123, 231, 123, 123, 231, 231]
b = [100, 123, 200, 231, 300, 231, 123]
```

В первом массиве повторяющие элементы. А во втором некоторые элементы их повторяют.
Мне нужно во втором массиве заменить элементы которые повторяются с первым массивом заменить на другое значение, например на "0".
То есть результат должен быть таким:

```py
b = [100, 0, 200, 0, 300, 0, 0]
```

Я пробовал так:

```py
a = IN[0]
b = IN[1]

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i==j:
            b[j]=0
```

Comment: что бы узнать, что элемент есть в массиве, можно цикл спрятать в конструкцию `for i in range(len(b)): if b[i] in a: b[i]=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` -- значение текущего элемента в цикле, а не его индекс. Обращаясь к элементу как `b[j]`, вы пытаетесь обратиться при первом же совпадении к элементу с индексом, выходящим за пределы массива.

Лучше перебирать индексы через `range(len())` :

```py
a = [123, 231, 123, 231, 123, 123, 231, 231]
b = [100, 123, 200, 231, 300, 231, 123]


for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if a[i]==b[j]:
            b[j] = 0
            
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Простой способ получить нужный результат - использовать списковое включение, тогда получится новый список с требуемым содержимым.

```
out = [0 if el in a else el for el in b]
```

Если требуется модифицировать именно старый список, не создавая новый, удобно использовать `enumerate()`

```
for i,el in enumerate(b):
    if el in a:
        b[i]=0
print(b)
```

```
[100, 0, 200, 0, 300, 0, 0]
```

Дополнительно. Если список `a` большой, то существенно сократить время на поиск элементов в нем можно за счет формирования множества (set) из списка и последующего определения наличия элемента уже в нем:

```
set_a = set(a)
out = [0 if el in set_a else el for el in b]
```